# Rest api - Query Multiple Sharepoint lists for a listitem with a given property value

Tags: 2010, rest, splistitem, cross-list

I have 3 sharepoint lists with the same columns. I need to fetch the list items with a particular property value, eg. CustomName property with value 'Test' from all the 3 lists. Instead of looping through each list I would like to retrieve all the list items with a single call.

The Rest api to fetch an item from a given list is below

```
http://server/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestList?$Filter=Title eq 'Test1'
```

But this means I have to make 3 calls, once for each list. Is there an API that I could use to query across all or multiple lists?

There is already a post explaining how to do this using the search API in sharepoint 2013. We are looking for a solution in Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score -1):

Well, we did not come across a way to fetch multiple lists in a single call with SP2010. Just posting this in hopes of helping someone who would be looking for a similar issue. So we had to make a call to each list individually.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Check this [answer]

Comment: @YashSaraiya, The intent was to convey the point that it is not possible to achieve what i tried to do. Appreciate if you could understand the intent before downvoting.

Comment: I do understand the intent. But as per the standards and guidelines of this forum, your answer qualifies as comment rather than an answer. Please note, it's not necessarily the person who comment had downvoted as well.